# Is there any better way to write an UPDATE query against the resulting table after a JOIN (SQL-server)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I have these tables:

[image]

I wrote the following query:

```sql
    UPDATE a
    SET a.AlbumTitle = 'An updated title!'

    FROM albums AS a
    JOIN RecordCompanies AS r
    ON a.RecordLabel = p.RCompanyId
    JOIN Singer AS s
    ON s.SingerId = a.Id_Author  


    UPDATE s
    SET s.SingerName = 'Updating the author too!'    

    FROM albums AS a
    JOIN RecordCompanies AS r
    ON a.RecordLabel = p.RCompanyId
    JOIN Singer AS s
    ON s.SingerId = a.Id_Author  


    UPDATE r
    SET r.RCompanyName = 'Updated RCompanyName too!'    

    FROM albums AS a
    JOIN RecordCompanies AS r
    ON a.RecordLabel = p.RCompanyId
    JOIN Singer AS s
    ON s.SingerId = a.Id_Author
```

Is there a better way to achieve that by using a *single query*? How could I improve my query?

Comment: SQL Server only allows you to update one table at a time in a single `update` query.  So you would still need multiple queries.

Comment: A DML statement can't effect multiple tables, no. As these are all very difficult columns, and tables, that you're effecting, then you will need 3 `UPDATE`statements.

Comment: Hi @Larnu. So my solution is correct?

Comment: @Gordon Linoff: could I execute a single UPDATE query against the result of the JOIN operation?

Comment: Assuming you have referential integrity, all of those additional `JOIN` constraints are redundant. For example the very first `UPDATE` simply updates every record with the same value right? So you could improve your query by removing all of those joins... assuming you are currently simply updating every single record

Comment: @nwdom . . . Your queries already use `JOIN`.  The issue is that SQL Server only allows you to update one table at a time.  You could create view and write an `instead of` trigger to update all three tables.  That seems rather cumbersome.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I have referential integrity and I need to upgrade - example - RCompanyName (RecordCompanies table), AlbumTitle (Albums table) and SingerName (Singer table) with the same UPDATE query (if possible but looks like it isn't). Could you explain me what you mean when you write 'by removing all of those joins'?

Comment: I'm pretty sure your first query can be written as `UPDATE albums SET AlbumTitle = 'An updated title!'`

Answer (score 0):

As the comments state, there isn't a way to do this in a single statement. I will just attempt to answer the question of 'how could I improve my query'.

Right now, your joins are unnecessary as without a WHERE clause, all records will be updated. I also cannot see a real-world scenario where you would need to update all three tables at the same time, but as long as you make sure your ID values are solid, the below should be a little easier to digest.

```
declare @singerID int
declare @albumID int
declare @companyID int

select
    @singerID = SingerID,
    @albumID = AlbumID,    
    @companyID = CompanyID
from
    Albums as A
    join Singer as S
        on A.Id_Author = S.SingerID
    join RecordCompanies as C
        on A.RecordLabel = C.RCompanyID
where
    A.AlbumTitle = 'OldAlbum'

update Albums set AlbumTitle = 'NewTitle' where AlbumID = @albumID
update Singer set SingerName = 'New Author' where SingerID = @singerID
update RecordCompanies set RCompanyName = 'New Company' where RCompanyID = @companyID
```